# How to customize Swiper navigation buttons in React?

Tags: swiper.js, react-swiper

I want to customize the navigation buttons in Swiper. but when I try to move the navigation buttons outside of the Carts, they are not visible.
I tried doing it manually with position but it didn't work :(
How to move it out of carts?

*Ps: I'm not good at English, so I apologize in advance if there are mistakes in the translation :)*[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any code - I'll make assumptions. All your cards are located in some container. This container can have `overflow: hidden`, so the cards won't be visible outside the defined area. And your pagination buttons should be somewhere outside of this area. You don't need to have them there, so you can just put them right after the container. Then you can make them absolute  and position them as you like

Comment: this is the default style of the swiper, if you turn off the "overflow: hidden" style in the swiper, the outside cards will be visible.

Comment: don't turn the overflow, you'll need it. but move the buttons outside the slider, so they won't be truncated because of this overflow